# create query in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

When we have to use

```
createQuery(String),   

createNamedQuery(String),  

createNativeQuery(String)
```

in Hibernate and what is the difference between them?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

createQuery:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-querying

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html

createNamedQuery:

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-named-query-examples/

http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/m91885316.html

createNativeQuery:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/querysql.html

Answer (score 17):

1. **CreateQuery**: Used to create an [HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html).
2. **createNamedQuery**: Used to define queries with name in mapping file or annotation. [See this.](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-named-query-examples/)
3. **createNativeQuery**: Used to execute native/pure SQL queries. [Example](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html)

Answer (score 4):

They differ in the meaning of the argument they are called with.

- createQuery takes an actual JP-QL query as argument.
- createNamedQuery takes the name of a query as argument, which is defined elsewhere, e.g. with a `@javax.persistence.NamedQuery` annotation.
- createNativeQuery is called with a SQL query.