# How to join tables using hibernate criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I am trying to join multiple table to join using criteria but getting error in doing so can someone please help me in it
My code is

```
final Session session = getSession();
final Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(ReferralPaymentInfo.class).createCriteria("SIGNUP_REFERRAL");
System.out.println("before");
List list = criteria.list();
System.out.println("after");
```

I also tried this code
    final Session session = getSession();
    final Criteria criteria  =session.createCriteria(ReferralPaymentInfo.class);
    criteria.setFetchMode("SIGNUP_REFERRAL", FetchMode.JOIN);
    List list = criteria.list();

This gives result only from table ReferralPaymentInfo and not considering table SIGNUP_REFERRAL
Can some one please help me out
T

Comment: I haven't used criteria query before, but as far as I know, you can't use references to the tables, you have to reference the entities in an criteria query. Edit your question to put ReferralPaymentInfo class, perhaps some people who knows more about criteria query can help you then.

Comment: if you need to use reference to tables not entities use nativeQuery
    
    session.createNativeQuery("XXXXX");

more info can be found here
https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=993904&view=next
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678591/create-query-in-hibernate

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
DetachedCriteria ownerCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Owner.class);
    ownerCriteria.setProjection(Property.forName("id"));
    ownerCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("ownername", "name"));

    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Pet.class);
    criteria.add(Property.forName("ownerId").in(ownerCriteria));
```

Comment: Can you please provide the sql for which you have written this Criteria

Comment: What is projection used for ?