# Getting error in joining tables using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

I am trying to join multiple table using hibernate but its not working for me can someone please help me out.
I tried Criteria that was not working then thought of using query even that is not working
My code looks like

```
 final Session session = getSession();
 String query = "SELECT r.REFERRER_ID from REFERRAL_PAYMENT_INFO r, SIGNUP_REFERRAL s";
 Query q = session.createQuery(query);
 List list = q.list();
```

I am getting this  error -

```
"Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: 
 REFERRAL_PAYMENT_INFO is not mapped [SELECT r.REFERRER_ID from REFERRAL_PAYMENT_INFO 
 r, SIGNUP_REFERRAL s]"
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use the classes (entities) you mapped in HQL queries. If you want to use normal SQL, then you have to call session.createSQLQuery().

Look at the documentation for hibernate session:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html

Comment: Thanks changing to SQLQuery works.Do you have any idea how to do the same usng criteria
I created a separeted thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620383/how-to-join-tables-using-hibernate-criteria but not got any satisfactory answer yet

Comment: @Rahul if the answer has helped you, you could consider accepting it.