# java spring : unexpected token: *

Tags: java, spring

In my jpa interface, i have the following code:

```
public interface ConsultationRequestRepository extends CrudRepository<ConsultationRequest, Integer> {

    @Query("select * from ConsultationRequest where status = ?1")
    List<ConsultationRequest> findRequestsByStatus(ConsultationStatus status);
}
```

but it complains with the error:

```
antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: *
```

what is wrong in this code?

Comment: You need to use hql query sintax, not sql queries to a @Query annotation. Supposing ConsultationRequest is an entity, the hql query may look something like this "SELECT cr FROM ConsultationRequest cr WHERE ...". You can look at the spring-jpa documentation here http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/ and also you have links to documentation in this stackoverflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678591/create-query-in-hibernate . Hopes this helps

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try to change your query in the following way:

```
@Query("select c from ConsultationRequest c where c.status = ?1")
```

Or you can use native query:

```
@Query("select * from ConsultationRequest where status = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
```

More about using `@Query` annotation you can find [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query)

Comment: For me this worked. "  @Query(value="select * from educational_gap_details  where employeeId = ?1",nativeQuery=true) "

Answer (score 3):

Never forget that **JPA is not SQL**, even if there is similar expression.
You want to get all entries and put it into a POJO or a list so you have to specify it in your *select* clause, like this :

```
public interface ConsultationRequestRepository extends CrudRepository<ConsultationRequest, Integer> {

    @Query("select c from ConsultationRequest c where status = ?1")
    List<ConsultationRequest> findRequestsByStatus(ConsultationStatus status);
}
```